# Factors for choosing between using a wrapper library or issuing command line process from my web application

Tags: web-applications, scalability, tesseract, ghostscript

I have a Java web application that makes use of certain libraries for example: Ghost Script for converting PDFs to TIFFs and Tesseract for OCR. There are java wrappers for both of these: Ghost4J and Tess4J.

What are some things I should think about when deciding whether to use the libraries or issue a command line process from my web application?

Off the bat what I'm noticing is that command line operations are slightly faster and don't take a toll on my application. For example 100 users sending PDFs that need to be converted to TIFFs using Ghost4j makes Java run at more that 100% CPU which makes the entire web application unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in a multi-user environment, try to utilize Ghost4J's high-level API components for multi-threading support.

http://www.ghost4j.org/threadsafetyandmultithreading.html